# how to use existing component in the dynamic loaded module component in angular

Tags: angular, angular-routing

is it possible to use loaded components with app.module.ts in dynamic future loading components using `loadClildren` as a tag?

I have a SharedTag component and declared in app.module and loaded when the bootstrap happen.

```
<shpared-tag></shared-tag>
```

I have another search component which will loaded dynamically as below.

```
  {
    path: 'search/:searchText',
    loadChildren: 'app/search/search.module#SearchModule'
  }
```

But when I try to use `<shpared-tag></shared-tag>` in dynamically loaded search component, it says shared-tag component is not available. But this component is already loaded with the app.module and available in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of angular-cli and webpack build this problem is resolved, you don't need to worry about the future component.

Webpack module loader to find the module and load them in the browser.